# Exception while running mapreduce example in mongo-hadoop

Tags: python, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

While am trying to run the example its showing some exception.I had referred the below link for reference

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-hadoop/

The exception as below,

```
 hduser@adminpc:/mongo-hadoop$ sudo ./gradlew jar testJar historicalYield
[sudo] password for hduser: 
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:examples/enron:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:examples/enron:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:examples/enron:classes UP-TO-DATE
:examples/enron:jar UP-TO-DATE
:examples/sensors:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:examples/sensors:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:examples/sensors:classes UP-TO-DATE
:examples/sensors:jar UP-TO-DATE
:examples/treasury_yield:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:examples/treasury_yield:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:examples/treasury_yield:classes UP-TO-DATE
:examples/treasury_yield:jar UP-TO-DATE
:flume:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:flume:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:flume:classes UP-TO-DATE
:flume:jar UP-TO-DATE
:hive:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:hive:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:hive:classes UP-TO-DATE
:hive:jar UP-TO-DATE
:integration-tests:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:integration-tests:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:integration-tests:classes UP-TO-DATE
:integration-tests:jar UP-TO-DATE
:pig:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:pig:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:pig:classes UP-TO-DATE
:pig:jar UP-TO-DATE
:streaming:compileJava
:streaming:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:streaming:classes
:streaming:jar UP-TO-DATE
:core:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:core:testsJar UP-TO-DATE
:examples/enron:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:examples/enron:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:examples/enron:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:examples/enron:testsJar UP-TO-DATE
:examples/sensors:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:examples/sensors:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:examples/sensors:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:examples/sensors:testsJar UP-TO-DATE
:examples/treasury_yield:compileTestJava
:examples/treasury_yield:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:examples/treasury_yield:testClasses
:examples/treasury_yield:testsJar UP-TO-DATE
:flume:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:flume:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:flume:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:flume:testsJar UP-TO-DATE
:hive:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:hive:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:hive:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:hive:testsJar UP-TO-DATE
:integration-tests:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:integration-tests:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:integration-tests:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:integration-tests:testsJar UP-TO-DATE
:pig:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:pig:processTestResources
:pig:testClasses
:pig:testsJar UP-TO-DATE
:streaming:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:streaming:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:streaming:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:streaming:testsJar UP-TO-DATE
:installHadoop
:installHive
:installPig
:copyFiles
Updating mongo jars
Updating cluster configuration
:startCluster FAILED

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * Where:
 Script '/mongo-hadoop/gradle/hadoop.gradle' line: 96

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':startCluster'.
> Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: false.
The following types/formats are supported:
- A String or CharSequence path, e.g 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'
- A String or CharSequence URI, e.g 'file:/usr/include'
- A File instance.
- A URI or URL instance.

* Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

please help me to sort out this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may have hit the issue fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/commit/5779bd4c0b4a88a71bdcb8142ba6661f59afe88c)

```
* Where:
 Script '/mongo-hadoop/gradle/hadoop.gradle' line: 96
```

Basically - the error message is telling you that the script failed on line 96 of `hadoop.gradle`.  If you look at this file (either locally or [on the mongodb github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/gradle/hadoop.gradle)), you see it is trying to delete `hadoop-tmpdir`.  The error message further tells you that it can't resolve the argument passed to delete to a file.

Note the most recent commit on the github is called `"Fix gradle delete for hadoop-tmpdir"`

Try editing your hadoop.gradle to match the one currently checked in on git.

Comment: first of all thank you for your support. The above issue has been fixed but its showing new error,-  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':historicalYield'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/local/bin/mongoimport''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: OK - that's a new question, so following the etiquette on here, you should accept the answer that fixed your problem and ask another.  Before asking the further question, try following the advice in the error message - Run the command with `--stacktrace`, `--info` and / or `--debug`.  That might allow you to solve the problem yourself.  If not, post another question with the original error and the detailed output and you will get better advice.